# Best way to use the Twitter API 1.1 with unauthenticated users

Tags: php, jquery, api, twitter, oauth

I apologize in advance for my English.

I need to get the last tweets about a specific subject (for example.. well.. Twitter!).

Today, i use https://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=twitter to obtain that.
But as you know this is deprecated and it will shutdown. So i try to use the 1.1 API with PHP (twitteroauth) but i have this issue:

*Every visitors of my website get the last twitter statuses about a subject with AJAX. If the visitor stay in my page, the twitter data will be refreshing all 10 seconds.*

**EDIT :** *Please note that i have a big amount of pages and the subject is different in every of them.*

Today, the majority of my visitors are not authenticated by my website, and by twitter.
If i use the PHP-way to get data and display to my visitors, i will be rate limited if the amount of my visitors are too high. There is my questions:

1. There is a way to build some "anonymous" token with my secret keys to "delegate" the rate limit window to my "anonymous" user?
2. If not, my use of the API 1.1 are realistic? How?
3. And, if not again, what is your recommandation, your advice to solve this?

Thank you very much for the enlightenment!

Comment: _“If i use the PHP-way to get data and display to my visitors, i will be rate limited if the amount of my visitors are too high.”_ – if you make a real API call for every page requested by any user, then yes. But you can easily “cache” the data on your server, and refresh it only when that cache is older than _X_.

Comment: That's true. But i have a big amount of pages and the subject is different in every of them. The cache is a good idea (thank you for that) but the rate limit risk is still here if i have for example 1000 unique visitors in distinct page.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to use the [streaming APIs](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-apis) with PHP CURL with AJAX to get my data.